# Feature Support For Different SDK Versions (IOS and Android) in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to work out what the earliest possible SDK version I can target for both IOS and Android using react native 0.44.

The only post I can find is now quite old :

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3617

It only talks about Android and it says that the earliest possible version is set in the `build.gradle` file under the variable `minSdkVersion`.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.facebook.react.tictactoe"
        minSdkVersion 16  //this is the one that dictates the lowest OS version
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
```

So can I just ask :

1. As it currently stands react native **does** support sdk 16 (which translates to Android Jellybean (4.1). This means that the documentation for 4.4 should just work with anything at these versions and above?
2. I am not sure how this translates into the IOS world. I see that the project.pbxproj has (IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 8). Does this mean that React Native 0.44 only supports IOS 8 and above?